# How do to setup button input for A-Frame

Tags: html, aframe

I am currently trying to get button input from the Oculus Touch buttons. I was able to attach a laser-controls to the control but I would like to be able to toggle the laser on and off. Not sure if this possible but I'm currently working with this setup that yields no response:

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('x-button-listener', {
    init: function() {
        var el = this.el;
        el.addEventListener('xbuttondown', function(evt) {
            var cameraEl = document.querySelector('#cameraRig[#left-hand]');
            cameraEl.removeAttribute('laser-controls');
        });
     }
 });
</script>
```

and

```
<a-entity id="cameraRig">
    <a-entity x-button-listener id="left-hand" teleport-controls="button: trigger; collision-entities: #ground" laser-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
</a-entity>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you register/include the component in the `<head>`? It looks correct on first glance...does `triggerdown` do anything?

Comment: I am not currently recording triggerdown. I am using the teleport-controls="button: trigger; collision-entities: #ground" which uses the trigger to teleport.

After some more testing, I used the example on the A-Frame site for the xbutton input and it made the entire Oculus controller disappear when I was trying to only affect the laser-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do `.setAttribute('raycaster', 'showLine', false)`, not remove `laser-controls`.

Comment: Thanks! That's the solution I needed. I'm relatively new to javascript so I've been relying on explicit examples of how to do certain things.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks odd. Don't you mean

```
document.querySelector('#left-hand')
```

or

```
document.querySelector('#cameraRig > #left-hand')
```

(see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors) for more information)